# JSON Object Response Error

Tags: php, android, json

```
public void searchLoginInfo(View view) {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray users = response.getJSONArray("users");
                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i);
                    String username = user.getString("username").toLowerCase();
                    String password = user.getString("password".toLowerCase());
                    String retypedpassword = user.getString("retypedpassword");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    if (username.equals(myLoginList.get(0)) && password.equals(myLoginList.get(1))) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent send = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(send);
                        break;
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent send = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(send);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley Error", error.toString());
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            if (networkResponse != null) {
                Log.e("Status code", String.valueOf(networkResponse.statusCode));
            }
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

I am using a JSON object request to get information from a database that I have created. I am able with my android application to insert data into the database but now I want to check for example if the user created an user account. Both the url and the php files work fine. I have used a log in the onErrorResponse method to see what is the actual error and I got this: **E/Volley Error: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**. I do not know what seems to be the problem with this. I have also checked using postamn if my web service is returning json data.[Printscreen with the json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqWFN.png)
 Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like Volley can't convert to json whatever string you're passing it. We'd really need to see what's being passed to Volley to determine what is wrong with it.

Comment: @saywhatnow how do I do that?

Comment: At every step, `Log.debug` the data so you can see what you're actually working with. 
If you ever don't understand why something is behaving in a particular way, look at it in smaller pieces. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `JSONRequest` try `StringRequest` and check if your response is valid json or not. `JSONRequest` tries to parse String into `JSONObject` and then returns and this will fail if response is not of type `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if you web service return a values.
You can test this with your navigator or with Postman for example.

Comment: I did that using postman and it returns json data. I have uploaded a photo. @SofDroid

Comment: You should be modify the ' JsonObjectRequest ' object with ' JsonArrayRequest '

Comment: And JSONObject with JSONArray

Comment: I did that and I got exactly the same error. The only difference is that now it says that the string cannot be converted to JSONArray insead of JSONObject as it previously did.

Comment: So, you have a error in your web server Json structor.